# Существительные на -ость

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

Буквально час назад столкнулась со странной закономерностью: резаный – резанность.

Существительное образовано суффиксальным способом, но, что очень странно, появилась ещё одна согласная, которой быть, по идее, не должно.

А вот в слове "леность", наоборот, она исчезла (ленный – леность).

Не подскажете, в чём парадокс, ведь, если судить по образованию с помощью морфемы -ость, такого происходить не должно?

На просторах интернета, к сожалению, ничего найти не удалось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А Вы слово **резанность** где нашли? В стихотворении И.Анненского "Снег"? Или у кого-то ещё? В словарях вы его не найдёте, это окказионализм (авторский неологизм) Анненского.

В современном русском языке отвлечённое существительное  от глагола резать - изрезанность (линий).

Поэт Аннинский - символист, его логика ясна: есть прилагательное  резаный, есть причастие  резанный (когда-то, кем-то, как-то). Ему важна экспрессия, действие, не внешний вид разделённости  линий, а именно результат действия природы, будто кто-то резал эти линии, поэтому его резанность - образование от причастия резанный.

Так что здесь другая закономерность - субъективное авторское восприятие. Образуется же прилагательное **желанный** **от глагола несов. вида **желать** **в значении совершенного вида (много раз желаемый - много раз желанный**), поэтому и пишется  -нн-.  Вот что-то похожее и здесь.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Просто как раз таки данное слово и ввело в некоторое затруднение, ведь с другими существительными не возникало проблем при образовании: абсолютно все из них подчинялись правилу.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Лень — леность.**

ЛЕНОСТЬ, ж. Склонность к лени; лень. Из-за лености остался без урожая. Л. одолела.

**2) Резонный — резонность.**

РЕЗОННЫЙ,  Разг. Весьма разумный, обоснованный. Р. довод. Р. совет. Р-ые замечания. <Резонно, нареч. Р. рассуждать. Р. говорить, утверждать. **Резонность,** -и; ж. Р. замечания. Р. предложения. Р. поступка.

Comment: Извините, но второе прилагательное не резонный, а резаный.

Comment: Слово "резанность" в словаре отсутствует, я могу предположить, что его вообще нет, так как оно не имеет смысла (как его определить). Скорее всего, это просто опечатка, да и орфографическая программа сообщает, что резонность - это самое близкое по форме слово.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но резанность (как уже выяснилось) – слово, придуманное самим автором, и именно поэтому возникли некоторые сложности при более детальном разборе.